# Instantiate choices.js when select field added dynamically

Tags: javascript

I'm using choices.js for select fields on a form and when one field is changed I do an AJAX request to the server and the server sends back another select field to add to the form. I need that field to be instantiated with choices.js

I'm instantiating my original fields with:

```
  const items = document.querySelectorAll('.js-choice');
  items.forEach((item) => new Choices(item));
```

but when I try to add something like that to my ajax code it complains that Choices isn't defined and it won't let me import it again because I'm not calling from a js module.

Is there a way to watch for new .js-choice elements and instantiate automatically?

Comment: _...and it won't let me import it again because I'm not calling from a js module._ -- Have you tried setting [`type="module"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Moduleshttps://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) to the script block?

Comment: Could we see how you are doing your AJAX request ? Seems you are having scoping issues. quick and dirty hack is to attach the choice library to the window object to have it available from anywhere : `window.Choices = Choices`

Comment: I managed to get my AJAX code to include the Javascript as type="module" so it works. Would still love a way to have Choices automatically instantiate added dom elements.

Comment: You could use a `MutationObserver` on the parent element of your items. Depending on the size of the parent tree, it can be quite expensive to monitor, if your items elements are deeply nested.